# Fill gaps from a parent in other rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this dataset that shows speed limits. The idea is that each region or city can apply its own rule, or “inherit” that of its parent entity.

```
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| country     | region                    | city                | max_speed |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      |                           |                     | 50        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                  |                     | 70        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                  | Saint-Grégoire      |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                  | Saint-Malo          | 30        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France             |                     |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France             | Saint-Cloud         |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France             | Vélizy-Villacoublay | 50        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     |                           |                     | 70        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     | Bayern                    |                     |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     | Bayern                    | Nürnberg            |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands |                           |                     | 90        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Gelderland      |                     |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie   Gelderland    | Harderwijk          |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland   |                     | 70        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland   | Haarlem             |           |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland   | Hoorn               | 30        |
+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Whenever a `max_speed` value is missing, it should be inferred as the value of the parent. For instance, the speed limit in *Saint-Grégoire* is that of *Bretagne*, while *Harderwijk* and *Nürnberg* apply the rule of the country (i.e. 90 and 70 respectively).

So, given this `DataFrame`:

```py
data = {'country': ['France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands'],
'region': [None, 'Bretagne', 'Bretagne', 'Bretagne', 'Île-de-France', 'Île-de-France', 'Île-de-France', None, 'Bayern', 'Bayern', None, 'Provincie Gelderland', 'Provincie Gelderland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland'],
'city': [None, None, 'Saint-Grégoire', 'Saint-Malo', None, 'Saint-Cloud', 'Vélizy-Villacoublay', None, None, 'Nürnberg', None, None, 'Harderwijk', None, 'Haarlem', 'Hoorn'],
'max_speed': [50, 70, None, 30, None, None, 50, 70, None, None, 90, None, None, 70, None, 30]}

speed_limits = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How do I fill in the missing values in `max_speed` to get:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| country     | region                  | city                | max_speed |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      |                         |                     |        50 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                |                     |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                | Saint-Grégoire      |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Bretagne                | Saint-Malo          |        30 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France           |                     |        50 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France           | Saint-Cloud         |        50 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| France      | Île-de-France           | Vélizy-Villacoublay |        50 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     |                         |                     |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     | Bayern                  |                     |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Germany     | Bayern                  | Nürnberg            |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands |                         |                     |        90 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Gelderland    |                     |        90 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Gelderland    | Harderwijk          |        90 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland |                     |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland | Haarlem             |        70 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Netherlands | Provincie Noord-Holland | Hoorn               |        30 |
+-------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I’ve been trying to create a function to apply to each row where `max_speed==np.NaN`, retrieve its parent (after determining if the missing value applies to a region or a city) and return its `max_speed` value, but, apart from not being very successful at doing that, I’m not even sure it’s the smartest approachs.

Any idea?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all parent (country) has a valid value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage `ffill()` to get the job done. First vertically propagate the country and region speed limits and set the city-only speed limit column.  Then propagate the speed limits left to right to get the inherited max speed limit.

Create a work dataframe:

```
wf = speed_limits.copy()
```

Copy and propagate the country speed limits:

```
wf['cntry_spd'] = pd.Series(np.where(wf['region'], np.nan, wf['max_speed'])).ffill()
```

Copy the region speed limits and propagate within region:

```
wf['reg_spd'] = np.where(~wf['region'].isna() & wf['city'].isna(), wf['max_speed'], np.nan)
wf['reg_spd'] = wf.groupby(['country','region'])['reg_spd'].ffill()
```

Create a city-only speed limit column:

```
wf['city_spd'] = np.where(~wf['city'].isna(), wf['max_speed'], np.nan)
```

Set the `max_speed` column on the `speed_limits DF` by forward filling NA's left to right across the `cntry_spd`,`reg_spd`,`city_spd` columns, inheriting speed limits that are not already set:

```
speed_limits['max_speed'] = wf[['cntry_spd','reg_spd','city_spd']].ffill(axis=1)['city_spd']
```

Result:

```
        country                   region                 city  max_speed
0        France                     None                 None       50.0
1        France                 Bretagne                 None       70.0
2        France                 Bretagne       Saint-Grégoire       70.0
3        France                 Bretagne           Saint-Malo       30.0
4        France            Île-de-France                 None       50.0
5        France            Île-de-France          Saint-Cloud       50.0
6        France            Île-de-France  Vélizy-Villacoublay       50.0
7       Germany                     None                 None       70.0
8       Germany                   Bayern                 None       70.0
9       Germany                   Bayern             Nürnberg       70.0
10  Netherlands                     None                 None       90.0
11  Netherlands     Provincie Gelderland                 None       90.0
12  Netherlands     Provincie Gelderland           Harderwijk       90.0
13  Netherlands  Provincie Noord-Holland                 None       70.0
14  Netherlands  Provincie Noord-Holland              Haarlem       70.0
15  Netherlands  Provincie Noord-Holland                Hoorn       30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my trial.
Documented and some print()s for debugging.
The query() statements are based on fact that pandas/NumPy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.
See one of the notes/warnings on this page https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

```
import pandas  as pd
data = {'country': ['France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands'],
'region': [None, 'Bretagne', 'Bretagne', 'Bretagne', 'Île-de-France', 'Île-de-France', 'Île-de-France', None, 'Bayern', 'Bayern', None, 'Provincie Gelderland', 'Provincie Gelderland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland', 'Provincie Noord-Holland'],
'city': [None, None, 'Saint-Grégoire', 'Saint-Malo', None, 'Saint-Cloud', 'Vélizy-Villacoublay', None, None, 'Nürnberg', None, None, 'Harderwijk', None, 'Haarlem', 'Hoorn'],
'max_speed': [50, 70, None, 30, None, None, 50, 70, None, None, 90, None, None, 70, None, 30]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#1)split the initial df in multiple dfs, using df.query():
# - countries - we assume that all of them have max_speed
# - regions - two categories
#   - max speed set
#   - max speed unset
# - cities - to categories 
#   - max speed set
#   - max speed unset
#
#2) use merge/join to update the max speed for the categories with max speed unset
#
#3) use append to cncatenate all sets, this is final result 
# replaced None/nan wit empty string for nice printing

# those will have speed set
# city compare is superflue, but for consistency
df_countries_only = df.query("(region != region) and (city != city) ")
print(df_countries_only)

# fix the regions
df_regions_to_fix = df.query("(city != city) and (max_speed != max_speed) and (region == region)")
df_regions_ok = df.query("(city != city) and (max_speed == max_speed) and (region == region)")

df_regions_speed = pd.merge(df_countries_only.drop(['region', 'city'], axis=1), 
        df_regions_to_fix.drop(['max_speed'], axis=1), how="inner", on=["country"])
df_regions_speed = df_regions_speed.append(df_regions_ok)
print(df_regions_speed)

df_cities_to_fix = df.query("(city == city) and (max_speed != max_speed)")
df_cities_ok = df.query("(city == city) and (max_speed == max_speed)")

df_cities_speed = pd.merge(df_regions_speed.drop(['city'], axis=1), 
        df_cities_to_fix.drop(['max_speed'], axis=1), how="inner", on=["country", "region"])

print(df_cities_speed)

# now rebuild final df
df_all_data = df_cities_speed.append(df_cities_ok).append(df_regions_speed).append(df_countries_only)
print("\n\n")
print(df_all_data.sort_values(by=['country', 'region', 'city']).fillna("")[['country', 'region', 'city', 'max_speed']])
```